# Automatic script dat sends .sql file to the database

Tags: sql-server, vps

Could someone me out, i have no idea where to start.

At the moment i have a game running on a VPS, this outputs a .sql with logs of ingame interactions,

I want to have some sort of script thats runs every 30m to send the logs.sql to the database to keep the log system up to date.

Maybe some sort of python script?

Please let me know if u might know something

Answer (score 0):

by simply writing a bash script and called it from a cron

here is an example of script :

```
#/bin/bash
mysql -uSQLUSER -pSQLPASSWORD < my_backup.sql
```

then call it in cron

```
crontab -e # get into the cron manager
*/30 * * * * /PATH_TO_YOU_BASH_SCRIPT/script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks bro i'll try it out

Comment: #Daan you may have to call mysql with /sbin/mysql in you bash script.

Comment: how do i connect to an online database? instead of the localhost

Comment: ?? please help me out haha i have to clue

Comment: Put this script on the server running your db.